# Network Animator not working in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ns2, nam

i successfully installed NAM on NS2, but when i run NAM with command nam, it gives following output.
nam:

Can anyone help , what the isssue is

Comment: Years 2014 - 2019 : The Debian / Ubuntu `nam` was corrupt. Valid packages are https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/ns-stop-couldn%27t-execute-nam-permission-denied-while-executing-exec-nam-4175524760/#2 ......... Any questions? Then please tell how NAM was installed.

Answer (score 0):

Requirements of ns-2

- gcc-4.8
- g++-4.8
  These were only available **up to Ubuntu 18.04**.

To properly install ns-2, it's essential to ensure these requirements are met. You can configure ns-2 for Ubuntu 20.04 using the instructions provided in this [article](https://www.nsnam.com/2023/02/ns2-installation-in-ubuntu-2204.html) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tH0yrJdovWM&t=3s).

Another crucial point: if you are **unable to fulfill these requirements**, **ns-2 might not work correctly on Ubuntu**. In such cases, the best approach is to opt for a **lower version of Ubuntu** that supports these requirements.

If you're using an **ARM-based version of Ubuntu**, you **won't be able to satisfy these requirements** either. In this situation, it's recommended to use a downgraded version of Ubuntu (Not ARM-based version) that meets these requirements.